# How to pass Schema in Postman for XML Responses?

Tags: json, xml, schema, postman, xml2js

I have received Successful response for a SOAP Post Request in Postman which is well explained in [this link](https://www.krengeltech.com/2017/05/tutorial-using-postman-to-test-xml-web-services/). But I want to know how can I pass the Schema for XML responses by the **Snippet**: *Use tiny validator for json data* which is used often to validate JSON Schema.

Endpoint:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx

Body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
   <FahrenheitToCelsius xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
     <Fahrenheit>100</Fahrenheit>
   </FahrenheitToCelsius>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
            <FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>37.7777777777778</FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>
        </FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```